# Any Open-Source, Free Software That Can Be Used to Computationally Calculate Binding Affinity Between Two Molecules?

Tags: software, reference-request, software-recommendations, molecular-modeling, crystallography

There are programs out there which calculate the binding affinity between a ligand and a target protein (Autodock 4, Autodock Vina, Chimera... etc). Is there any analogous program that can be used to calculate the binding affinities between two molecules?

For my purposes, I'd like to computationally determine the binding affinity between crystalline hydroxyapatite and an analogue of a bisphosphonate molecule.

Comment: Do you want to compute the binding affinity in aqueous phase or in the gas phase? Is this binding process a purely vdW + hydrogen bond interaction, or does it also involve coordination? If you are studying the binding in the aqueous phase, do you already know from the literature how the crystal surface is reconstructed as a result of its interaction with water? What is the desired level of accuracy (e.g. 5 kcal/mol? 2 kcal/mol?)

Comment: 1. The binding affinity would be calculated in the aqueous phase. 2. Coordination is involved. 3. I'm not too familiarized with the form the crystal structure would take, though I know it would become a hydrate in solution. That is, any O- would become OH, and associated Ca2+ ions would complex with water to form CaOH. 4. Lower uncertainties are always better, but I'm open to exploring any software capable of performing the computational assay.

Comment: @wzkchem5 the user responded, but didn't ping you.

Comment: Mas, have you figured out the answer now? Please update us! It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue now that it's been more than 8 months!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned (OP hasn't returned for several months). It can be reopened if the OP expresses renewed interest.